# how to find Max date in pandas with NaN values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I did spend few hours trying to find solution for my question and was not able to find any good working solution.
I have Pandas table and i need to find Max Date from date column:

```
0    2022-07-07
1           NaN
2    2022-07-08
3           NaN
4    2022-07-10
```

I'm trying something like that:

```
df['date'].max()  -> "Not supported between instances "srt" and "float""
```

I also tried add `numeric_only=true` and then `is_nan=True`

Then even numpy way: `numpy.nanmax(df.iloc['date'].value)  -> cannot index by location index`

Can someone tell me how to use Pandas and get MAX value from 1 column, if there is some strings and NaN in it??

thank you,

Comment: Please read about how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The string `"Nan"` is not the same as `NaN`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first need to convert to a `datetime` object then find maximum:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date']).max()
Timestamp('2022-07-10 00:00:00')
```